# Constructing and populating a 2D array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a 2D array of

`int[,] graph = new int[totalNumberOfCaves, totalNumberOfCaves]`

In this case the value `totalNumberOfCaves = 7`

I would then like to populate this with values from an `list<int>` named `connectionWeight` which will contain a total of `totalNumberOfCaves * totalNumberOfCaves` in this case 49.

I think I have the 2D array construction correct but I am unsure as how to add the values of `connectionWeight` to this array at the points needed.

the 2D array is built as follows;

```
int[,] graph = new int[totalNumberOfCaves, totalNumberOfCaves];
for (int i = 0; i < graph.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < graph.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        graph[i, j] = connectionWeight["Value at possition"];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this or get the values added at the correct point would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this code needs to be improved? Seems very readable and easy to understand from where I stand...

Comment: coonnectionWeight would contain a total of 49 right? 7*7=49.

Comment: @ZoharPeled its to see where i would add the loop to count over the position of the value needed from `connectionWeight` as it should increment by 1 when the construction loop finishes. for example when the value`[0,0]` is added to the array the first value of `connectionWeight` should populate that array position. hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Matthew correct, my mistake. corrected now

Comment: you don't need to count, cant you do `connectionWeight[i*totalNumberOfCaves+j]`?

Comment: @Matthew I tried that however I am getting an error stating that `start index cannot be less than zero` I'm not sure why this is happening?

Comment: @bdg where did you place it

Comment: @Matthew my mistake, was referring to a different part of the code, `graph[i, j] = connectionWeight[i*7+j];` appears to have done the trick.

Comment: glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph[i, j] = connectionWeight[i * 7 + j];
```

will do the trick. Otherwise I suppose there is no problem with the way you fill in your 2D array.